# Telerik RadDocument table sizing issues

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, rad-controls

I have a RadDocument and a table in that document.

If the user drags upwards to size-down a row to the content, upon release the row snaps back and sizes to just more than the content.

This can be rectified by dragging the row guide in the ruler, but this is a fairly sub-optimal solution for the end-users.

Is there a way of preventing the snap-back behaviour?

**EDIT**

Further investigation shows that the snap-back behaviour isn't exhibited if the row is over a certain height to begin with.

Perhaps there's a minimum size property interfering somewhere? Though resizing using the guide still violates this.

Comment: A bit of code would be nice :)

Comment: @devhedgehog there isn't any code involved, it's quite literally just a table in a RadDocument unfortunately.

Comment: I get you its just a demo example with all dlls inside would help us debug and visualize your problem better. I would like to have the example in front of me and then to snoop height or width property. Snoop is the name of a great tool. You can get it on codeplex. Have you posted this poblem on a telerik forum? Maybe they know more...

Comment: @devhedgehog unfortunately it's proprietary employer code so I can't really share anything. It is quite literally just a RadDocument with a table in it with the standard RadDocument UI with ruler guides etc.

Comment: Ok I get your point. Well try install Snoop and play with Width and Height properties. Force InvalidateMeasure() method to be called to see how RadDocuments measures its tables. It will be hard to help without any demo.

Comment: What version of the rad controls are you using?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am aware of the Height property of a TableRow is only set when you import a document that specifies explicitly the Height of table rows, you change the height of a TableRow using the DocumentRuler (or the thumbs that are shown when you hover the Table). In general, the document takes care to calculate the Height of a table when you enter text in it, so in your case I think that is what is causing the snap back because there is a min height. You can easily write a code that sets the max height or min height. Also, I know GridView has event handler for rows you might want to use a GridView instead.